# Bukkit Permissions: Owner group not giving me all permissions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am running a Minecraft server with Bukkit and everything works fine. I set up the permissions using Group Manager and the Default group works well. However, I added myself to the Owner group and do not have all permissions.

How can I make it so that I have all permissions? I tried using the `*` and `bukkit.command.*` nodes with no luck, along with being op.

Comment: If you are op you should get all permissions no matter what group you are in.

Comment: you could just not be in a group at all (if its because of the prefix, use a plugin to give yourself a prefix. http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/simple-prefix/

Comment: @RustyMembers In some cases, GroupManager overrides op.

Comment: @RustyMembers I gave myself the permission node, * in the users files, but still do not have all permissions.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If you downvote something, you should leave a comment saying why....

Comment: @avestar101 No. Commenting is NOT required with downvotes. Read the relevant [meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system).

Comment: @shanodin I know, but if everyone just left a comment, then the people who have been downvoted can see what is wrong with their answer and improve their questions in the future.

Comment: Just read the discussion I linked, it's all been said before. If someone doesn't think a question is a fit for the site, or has problems, or whatever, they are free to downvote, and they always will be.

Comment: Can you paste the Owner group part in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You might have made a mistake somewhere in the permission file. Are you sure that you are in the group – do you have the prefix/suffix from the group? If not, you might have added yourself to the wrong group or the wrong world.

Comment: He says he's already an op

Comment: @shanodin I've removed that bit. The rest is ok, and that "didn't read the whole question" bit doesn't need to stay and drag the rest of the answer down.

Answer (score 1):

The node is '*' to give all permissions. If OP doesn't override the permissions and you want it to, then you should change that in the config.yml of groupmanager.

Answer (score 1):

GroupManager is outdated and you should use other permission manager. PermissionsEX is good variant.

Comment: This answer would be better as a comment